# Como colocar um item de um menu breadcrumb com uma cor diferente, sem o hover

Tags: css, menu

Tenho um menu deste gênero, mas não quero usar o estado de `hover`. Ele vai servir apenas para informação da página, sem ser necessário clicar.

No entanto, não estou a conseguir colocar uma cor diferente num dos menus, sem estar a usar um estado de `hover`. Já tentei usar uma classe diferente, com uma cor diferente, e não estou a conseguir.

Abaixo meu código:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

<title>breadcrumbs</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    body{
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

        }
    #crumbs ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 15px;
    background: #999;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 30px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1px;
    cursor:default;
}

    #crumbs ul li a:after {
    content: "";  
    position: absolute; right: -17px; top: 0;
    border-top: 17px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid #999; 
    z-index: 1;
}
    #crumbs ul li a:before {
    content: "";  
    border-top: 17px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid #fff;
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
}

    #crumbs ul li {
    display:inline;
}

    #crumbs ul li a:hover {
    background: #779519;
}
    #crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
        border-left-color: #779519;
    }    


    #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-top-left: 10px; border-bottom-left: 10px;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
    display: none; 
}

#crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    padding-right: 80px;
    border-top-right: 10px; border-bottom-right: 10px;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
    display: none; 
}

    </style></head>

<body>
    <div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tipo de Bilhete / Zona</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sector</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lugar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dados de Reserva</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ConfirmaÃ§Ã£o</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pagamento</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Embora não consiga perceber porque razão queres o hover se não vais usar esse estado. Não faz muito sentido. Em todo o caso podes usar javascript e adicionares uma classe por JS. Em todo o caso, o evento hover vai ser despoletado.

Comment: Já resolvi, obrigado.

Comment: Compartilhe a resposta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só inserir uma `class="active"` na li que deseja destacar. No CSS fica

`#crumbs ul li.active a {...}`

Seu código com a alteração:

```html
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

<title>breadcrumbs</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    body{
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

        }
    #crumbs ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 15px;
    background: #999;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 30px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1px;
    cursor:default;
}

    #crumbs ul li a:after {
    content: "";  
    position: absolute; right: -17px; top: 0;
    border-top: 17px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid #999; 
    z-index: 1;
}
    #crumbs ul li a:before {
    content: "";  
    border-top: 17px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid #fff;
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
}

    #crumbs ul li {
    display:inline;
}

    #crumbs ul li a:hover {
    background: #779519;
}
    #crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
        border-left-color: #779519;
    }    


    #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-top-left: 10px; border-bottom-left: 10px;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
    display: none; 
}

#crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    padding-right: 80px;
    border-top-right: 10px; border-bottom-right: 10px;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
    display: none; 
}


#crumbs ul li.active a{
    color: #ffcc00;
    background: #000;
}

    </style></head>

<body>
    <div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tipo de Bilhete / Zona</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sector</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lugar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dados de Reserva</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ConfirmaÃ§Ã£o</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Pagamento</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Pelo que entendi você quer que o usuário saiba a localização dele sem o hover. Acredito que você mesmo já encontrou a solução, mas não aplicou.

Se você estiver utilizando um gerenciador por exemplo, a tag body sempre possui uma classe com a informação do id da página por exemplo:

```
<body class="page-contato"></body>
```

A partir dai você pode ter controle controle do CSS utilizado na página de forma individual também.

Se não tiver utilizando nenhum CMS, basta utilizar esta mesma lógica.

Segue o exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/AquilesOliveira/pc7vgcxz/